# Set default size for image and crop if it/zoom in if it exceeds or is too small

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Say I have a 500x1500 sized image.  What I want is when I display it, I want the default size to be 500x500, but without stretching it - it should crop it and only show the center. Or if the image is 250x500, I'd want it to zoom in to 500x500 instead of stretching it awkwardly.

The css for my image element:

```
  display: block;
  height: 40%;
  background: no-repeat center;
```

It's still stretching.

Note: I also tagged Ionic since I'm using Ionic so just in case there's a solution in Ionic for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `object-fit: cover`

This will cut off the excess, preserve the aspect ratio, and scale to fit the space.

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp